# How to change URL without redirect?

Tags: javascript, url

I am trying to add country name for every link in page my website. It is redirecting two times. How can I change URL without redirecting?

```
$(document).on('click',function(e){
    var querystring = '?country=' + countrySelected;
    
    
    if(e.nodeName === "A"){
        window.location = window.location.href + querystring;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Zoltan Toth

Comment: I used the following it is works like a cham...if(e.nodeName === "A"){
  var newTarget = window.location.href + querystring;
}

Answer (score 11):

Use the hash tag - #

```
var querystring = '#country=' + countrySelected;
```

It's used heavily in single page applications, because it doesn't redirect.

Comment: Could you add explanation on the `#` string as anchor?

Comment: Along with this, you (op) will need to replace the hash on each change of the value, and it's also worth noting that a hash cannot be read by server side languages.

Answer (score 4):

### Navigate to fragment

To properly [navigate to fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39921800/402022) you need a target element, marked with and `id` or `name` attribute you reference in the anchor. To be precise, following a link with `#foo` will scroll the element with `id="foo"` or else the element with `name="foo"`.

Note: the recommendation is to **not** use the `name` attribute for this purpose. Virtually all browsers will support navigating to an element by its `id` attribute. *Except, perhaps, old Netscape 4 (1997), IE4 (1997) or older browsers, can't test this. Making an hyperlink to a position in the page was already present in the [RFC1866](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1866.txt) of 1995.*

The found element will also be made active. That implies that you can apply css to it by using the pseudo selector `:active`.

CSS3 also defines the pseudo selector `:target` to be applied on the target element.

**[Browser compatibility for the target pseudo selector](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3):**

- Chrome:  1+
- Chrome for Android:  51+
- UC Browser for Android:  9.9+
- iOS Safari:  3.2+
- Firefox: 3.5+
- IE:  9+
- Opera Mini:  All
- Samsung Internet:    4+
- Android Browser: 2.1+
- Safari:  3.2+
- Edge:    12+
- Opera:   10.1+

---

### History API

If navigating to fragment isn't good enough for you, consider using the history API. I'm Taking this example from the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API):

Suppose http://example.org/foo.html executes the following JavaScript:

```
var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
```

This will cause the URL bar to display http://example.org/bar.html, but won't cause the browser to load bar.html or even check that bar.html exists.

Read more at [diveintohtml5.info](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html) and [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/using-the-html5-history-api/).

**[Browser compatibility for History API](https://caniuse.com/#feat=history):**

- Chrome:  5+
- Chrome for Android:  51+
- UC Browser for Android:  9.9+
- iOS Safari:  5.0-5.1+
- Firefox: 4+
- IE:  10+
- Opera Mini:  None
- Samsung Internet:    4+
- Android Browser: 4.2-4.3+
- Safari:  6+
- Edge:    12+
- Opera:   11.5+

Dive Into HTML5 suggests the following method to detect compatibility:

```
function supports_history_api() {
  return !!(window.history && history.pushState);
}
```

The idea is that `window.history` and `history.pushState` wouldn't have been defined in a browser that doesn't support the History API.

Comment: Please note that HTML5 History API is from IE10 (including)

Comment: @timenomad Added compatibility notes as per request.

Answer (score 2):

You can use history API

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/History

```
history.pushState([data], [title], [url]);

var querystring = 'country=' + countrySelected;

history.pushState("", document.title, querystring);
```

Ref: https://css-tricks.com/using-the-html5-history-api/

Answer (score 1):

Does the webpage do something different if you are in a different country?  If it does, then it would require the browser to load the page that is for the selected country(thereby requiring a redirect).  If the webpage does something different for the selected country, but it requires another parameter to actually do something that requires a country-specific addition to the URL, then you would be better off with something like:

```
var countrystring = '?country=" + countrySelected;
// code to make var querystring = the rest of 
// the requirements for the country to do something
// and your code to verify what the user has entered
addstring = countrystring + querystring;
window.location = window.location.href +addstring;
```