# How to change the page url without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, .htaccess, meta

I want to know how can I change the *page URL* without *reloading the page* or *changing the page content*.
I already use that code (**JavaScript**):

```
if(history.pushState){
  window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/");
}else{
  document.location.href = "/";
}
```

But it doen't work in all browsers and *Firefox* marks it as *insecure*.
Is there other ways to do what I want in **JavaScript**/**jQuery**/.**htaccess**/**HTML meta tags**

**EDIT:**
  **(1):** I want an answer that doesn't use `window.history.pushState`
  **(2):** Those answers don't help:
 [how to chage url without redirect in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39921761/how-to-chage-url-without-redirect-in-javascript)
, [How do I modify the URL without reloading the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/how-do-i-modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to chage url without redirect in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39921761/how-to-chage-url-without-redirect-in-javascript)

Comment: no, that doesn't

Comment: Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/how-do-i-modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page

Comment: I want something that doesn't include `window.history.pushState` because it's not safe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTML5 replaceState if you want to change the url but don't want to append this entry to the browser history:

```
if(window.history.replaceState){
   window.history.replaceState(STATEDATA, TITLE, URL);
}
```